# What is the name of this flower?

Tags: flowers

During my travels of the Australian countryside as a tourist I encountered this flower in the wild numerous times along the Great Ocean Road. I love the bright violet color and would love to buy seeds for my garden at home.

What is it's name?

[image: Aster]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Carpobrotus rossii. Edible fruit, can become a weed. Not likely to survive winter and become a weed in Germany.

Answer (score 0):

It is an Iceplant (Delosperma), possibly [this](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delosperma_ashtonii#/media/Fichier:Delosperma_ashtonii.jpg) one (Delosperma ashtonii). The genus tends to be fairly tender (US zone 6 is typically its coldest zone) and likes very good drainage and a dry climate.